# Position relative not working in Firefox on table-cell elements?

Tags: html, css, firefox

This code is part of a bigger thing however for simplicity I tried to make it as minimal as possible. I have absolute positioned span tags within relative positioned anchor link, in every browser it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/ee7kq/. In firefox it appears the span elements are positioned based on the NAV instead of the anchor because everything lines up to the left side or right instead of positioning correctly inside the anchor

**HTML**

```
<nav>
 <a><span class="num">1</span><span class="name">Words</span></a>
 <a><span class="num">2</span><span class="name">Words</span></a>
 <a><span class="num">3</span><span class="name">Words</span></a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav { position: absolute; display: table; width: 100%; }
nav a { position: relative; display: table-cell; border: 1px solid #d8d8d8; height: 50px;}
nav a .num { left: 0; position: absolute;  }
nav a .name { right: 0; position: absolute; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ee7kq/ **how i want it to look**
http://jsfiddle.net/ee7kq/1/ **how it looks in firefox**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position) states that:

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

As it is undefined what do to here, Firefox rightfully choose to ignore the position on your `table-cell` elements, making the container the nearest anchor.

Either do not use `table` displays, or wrap the positioned elements again in a `block` element and put the `position: relative` there instead of the `table-cell` element.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ee7kq/3/).

```
<style>
nav {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
nav a {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    height: 50px;
}
nav div {
    position: relative;
}
nav a .num {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
nav a .name {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<nav>
    <a><div><span class="num">1</span><span class="name">Words</span></div></a>
    <a><div><span class="num">2</span><span class="name">Words</span></div></a>
    <a><div><span class="num">3</span><span class="name">Words</span></div></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: any known hacks to fix this for firefox, not goin to like rewriting all my css to fix this :(

Comment: You'll have to wrap it if you want keep using `table-cell`. Updated my answer and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
position: relative;
```

does not appear to work in conjunction with

```
display: table-cell;
```

You can wrap your spans in another element set to

```
display: block;
position: relative;
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ee7kq/2/